# Override the userid send by Websphere MQ Client in C# Windows application

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, windows

I am trying to connect to a test instance of a Websphere MQ 7.5 server (on a Windows domain) from a C# application using the full MQ Client install, but I've had no luck. I keep getting the error code **2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED** from the MQ server. Initially I tried the code below:

```
string QueueManagerName = "myNewQManager";
MQEnvironment.Hostname = "tst-mqsvr";
MQEnvironment.Channel = "test.channel";
MQEnvironment.Port = 1414;
MQEnvironment.UserId = "domainUser";
MQEnvironment.Password = "********";
//set transport properties.
MQEnvironment.properties[MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY] = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;
try
{
    queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName);
}
catch(MQException mqexp)
{
    //I get the error code 2035
    log.Error(mqexp)
}
```

changing to this doesn't work either:

```
string QueueManagerName = "myNewQManager";
var queueProperties = new Hashtable();
queueProperties[MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY] = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;
queueProperties[MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY] = "tst-mqsvr";
queueProperties[MQC.PORT_PROPERTY] = "1414";
queueProperties[MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY] = "test.channel";
queueProperties[MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY] = "domainUser";
queueProperties[MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY] = "*********"; 
try
{
    queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, queueProperties);
}
catch(MQException mqexp)
{
    //I still get the error code 2035
    log.Error(mqexp)
}
```

This error goes away and I can connect/put/get messages from my queue if

- I manually set the MCAUSER on my channel, or
- I run the application as the domain user who set up the MQ server (using RunAs)

However, I will not be able to use either of these two workarounds for the production set up. I am assuming I'm getting the error code 2035 because the MQ client is sending the wrong user-id. I need to be able to override (or at least determine) the flowed userid during server connection. How do I go about this?

Edit: I got the errors below in my AMQERR01.log file

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7/6/2016 13:06:14 - Process(1380.10) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(TST-MQSVR) Installation(DefaultInstall)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(MYNEWQMANAGER)

AMQ8075: Authorization failed because the SID for entity 'sinistrian' cannot be
obtained.

EXPLANATION:
The Object Authority Manager was unable to obtain a SID for the specified
entity. This could be because the local machine is not in the domain to locate
the entity, or because the entity does not exist.
ACTION:
Ensure that the entity is valid, and that all necessary domain controllers are
available. This might mean creating the entity on the local machine. 
----- amqzfubn.c : 2273 -------------------------------------------------------
7/6/2016 13:06:14 - Process(1380.10) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(TST-MQSVR) Installation(DefaultInstall)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(MYNEWQMANAGER)

AMQ8073: Authorization failed because SID: ((None)) could not be resolved.

EXPLANATION:
The Object Authority Manager was unable to resolve the specified SID into
entity and domain information.
ACTION:
Ensure that the application provides a SID that is recognized on this system,
that all necessary domain controllers are available, and that the security
policy is set as you required. 
----- amqzfubn.c : 4397 -------------------------------------------------------
7/6/2016 13:06:14 - Process(3008.3) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(TST-MQSVR) Installation(DefaultInstall)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(MYNEWQMANAGER)

AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID failed with CompCode 2 and Reason 2035.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again. 
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 1975 -------------------------------------------------------
7/6/2016 13:06:14 - Process(3008.3) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(TST-MQSVR) Installation(DefaultInstall)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(MYNEWQMANAGER)

AMQ9999: Channel 'TEST.CHANNEL' to host 'WKS-L450 (192.168.10.23)' ended
abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 3008(2192) for channel
'TEST.CHANNEL' ended abnormally. The host name is 'WKS-L450 (192.168.10.23)';
in some cases the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide.
```

Comment: What does your queue manager AMQERR01.LOG say? There are many reasons for a 2035 error when you look at the detail, and those details are in the error log. Without them we'd just be guessing.

Comment: @MoragHughson I've included the error log contents

Comment: I've found the answer to my question in the logs. Thanks @MoragHughson

Comment: The error logs are always a great place to look. Remember to look there every time you have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [MQS_REPORT_NOAUTH](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&uid=swg21299319) or [MQSAUTHERRORS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21377578) setting to get more info the authority failure.

Comment: I understand that the MQS_REPORT_NOAUTH environment variable does NOT need to be set for MQ version 7.1 and higher, as the trace is generated by default. However, I set MQSAUTHERRORS as an environment variables on the MQ Server but no FDC file was created.

Comment: The FDC would be created on the server where the queue manager exists.  Did you set the environment variable there and check for FDCs as well as the logs for the AMQ8077 error?

Comment: Yes, I set environment variable on the server where the queue manager is. I can see the logs, but no FDC file.

Comment: What directory are you looking for FDCs?  The AMQ8077 error should tell you the ID and reason for access failure.

Comment: I am looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\qmgrs\myNewQManager\errors\; i can see AMQERR01.LOG, AMQERR02.LOG and AMQERR03.LOG (the last two are empty).

Comment: I've included the error log contents in my question

Comment: I just realized that the answer to my question is in this same log file: **AMQ8075: Authorization failed because the SID for entity 'sinistrian' cannot be
obtained.**. Thanks Valerie

Comment: glad the logs showed the answer and it seems like you were looking for FDCs in wrong location.  Try C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\errors  Refer to this technote:  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21173468#Windows

Answer (score 1):

Until version 7.5, MQ client always flows the logged-in UserId and not the UserId specified by the application, to queue manager for authorization. You will need a security exit for this scenario.

This changed in MQ v8 where UserId specified by the application is flowed to the queue manager for authorization check. More details here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q113260_.htm

Comment: I cant upgrade to MQ v8 at this time. I now need to detect what UserId is being flowed to the queue manager so that I can create a rule for it on the channel.